# iOS-like icons grid in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to have a view in my OS-X (Lion) application for displaying icons in a grid that when clicking an icon, the view changes to a different view (depends on the icon clicked) with a similar animation to iOS when clicking an app icon.

What's the best way to that with writing the minimal amount of code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection view. The view of each item should be a button whose action you respond to by swapping the collection view out for the appropriate destination view (perhaps by switching tabs in a tabless tab view).